# Convert bitmap bits from GetDIBits to jpeg for winsock transmission

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi+, gdi

I am making a screenshot and retreiving the bits of the bitmap into a char buffer. I am wanting to send this over winsock to another program. This is successfull but sending the bitmap is processor consuming so I would like to compress the bitmap to send over winsock.

What libraries or methods of GDI should i use?
I am not familiar with GDI+, so I would prefer non GDI+ solutions. If GDI+ is needed, any links to good tutorials is appreciated.

Once i recieve the bits from server to client, how would i display it back>? Does normal bitblt functions work with the buffer or how can i do this?

THank you.

Comment: Is lossy compression allowed? If so, use the JPEG format. This is not available in gdi, but it is in gdi plus. If you dont want gdiplus, there are open source jpeg libraries. For screenshots, png format might even work better.

Comment: If the goal is just to reduce bandwidth, then converting to another image format is pretty pointless when you can just compress the bitmap data as-is using real compression like gzip.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I understand your point, but JPEG's compression is certainly "real". "Lossless" (or perhaps "generic", as opposed to picture-oriented) would've been a better description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert bitmap to jpeg, I think you can use the open source library which is called jpeglib. Maybe it can help you.

But in my opinion, if you just change the format of the screenshot, it's not a good idea. I think you should use compression algorithm to compress the screenshot, then send it to the client. Nice day.

Comment: Ok, what library do you reccommend? My image is stored in an unsigned char array using new. Its 2800000 bytes size and that is too much to send over winsocket.

Comment: Once, I had a project. The server send me a picture which format is jpeg, but I need convert the jpeg to bitmap and then show the bitmap on the MFC control.

Comment: First, your picture data is so large that will waste some time to transfer. But I am not familiar with ZLib. I searched. I think it will work. You asked how to display it back. You must know the struct of the bitmap.

Comment: I do the Zlib compression first, and then send over winsock. Its for a remote control like application. Ill probably be capturing around 10-15 frames per second here.

Comment: When transmitting images in sequence simulating real-time video, you can cut out a lot of bandwidth by sending only differences from one image to the next instead of sending the full images every time. Send a base image, then send only the pixels that have changed since the last image, and so on. The receiver shows the base image then overlays the changes on top of it. Every so often, send a new full base image for re-syncing.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think it is a good idea. But It is full of challenge.@Kelvin I want to know whether the client application shows the screenshot as the original size. If not, you can scale the screenshot. Maybe it will take a better result.